# How session works on client-server architecture of Appium?

Tags: appium

I want to study details about how the Appium server works, so while studying about the architecture, I am not getting a clear idea about how the session works on Appium server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two components to running Appium automation tests - `Appium server` and `Appium session`. `Appium server` is a REST interface listener, while an `Appium session` is the entity which makes REST calls to `Appium server` in order to perform actions such as finding & clicking web elements. The session is tied to a device such as Android emulator or real device.

You can start an `Appium server` without starting an `Appium session`, but you cannot start an `Appium session` without starting an `Appium server`.

When you have Appium properly installed, you can open the Command prompt & enter `appium`. You will see a message indicating the Appium REST listener has started, and is listening on a specific address, such as `0.0.0.0:4327`.

When you start an `Appium session`, you have to ensure your session is connecting to the correct port. If you start `Appium server` on `0.0.0.0:4327`, but then try to start a session on `0.0.0.0:5555`, the session will not start.

The `Appium session` uses underlying libraries such as `node` and `Java` to interact with web elements. The code is publicly available on https://github.com/appium/appium so you can view the complete architecture and session / server relationship here if you'd like.